# MySQLi into Lightsale Database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysqli, amazon-lightsail

I have a remote database that I work with by running locally:

```
ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i my_key.pem bitnami@9.163.160.57
```

Then I manage the database at http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin, using "root" and "my_pw". I have created a "blogs" database via this connection.

How do I PHP / mysqli into the "blogs" database? I have been unsuccessful. Running my local xampp, I'm trying and failing with:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "my_pw";
$db = "blogs";
$port = 80;
$socket = 8888;

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pw,$db,$port,$socket);

if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
```

Comment: you have to open a tunnel first, look for mysqli and ssh

Comment: The first thing that jumps out to me is that you are passing port 80 in your configuration, however your SSH tunnel is exposing the database on 8888 via localhost. Managing a database through an SSH tunnel is pretty abnormal. Have you considered setting up a VPN connection to the database VM if you don't want to expose the database port? Or whitelisting your external IP Address as a firewall rule?

Comment: you can create a tunnel for the 3306 port the same way you created for 80

Comment: Right now, the code tries to connect mysqli to the phpmyadmin web-ui, which cannot work. mysqli needs to directly connect to the database port (usually `3306` if not configured otherwise). As @YourCommonSense said, we need to open another port-forward to remote port `3306` and rewrite the code so that it connect mysqli to that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems impossible, and it redirects me to try another, safer approach: develop on my local mysql, and only use the remote phpmyadmin to upload the local mysql to the website.

Comment: Is this a reply to a comment?